# USB mass storage device says the hub power has been exceeded

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

Everything was fine with my laptop [Toshiba Satellite L670](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_Satellite#List_of_Satellite_models), and suddenly I received a message something like "USB hub power exceeded..." and I clicked something (I was in a hurry and didn't pay attention). Now I can't use USB sticks, but can use a USB mouse though. In [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) in Properties section of "USB Mass Storage Device" the item says

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)".

I tried restarting the laptop, and nothing happened. I tried to uninstall this driver and ran "Check for hardware updates", system "finds" new "USB Mass Storage Device" driver, but it failed to install.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hardware problem. If you are familiar with Linux [live CDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), you could use one to test if your USB storage devices work in Linux. If they don't, you will be pretty sure it is indeed a hardware problem, and it is time to check with your manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some defective device tried to draw too much current and safeties engaged and disabled the port. The usual solution is to unplug the problematic device and go to Device Manager. There you'll find a list of internal hubs. One of them should have an exclemation mark next to it. Right click in it and click disable.

After that, right click on it again and choose enable. This should reset safely. If you can't find the broken hub, try the procedure for each hub on the list. Be careful if you're using a USB keyboard or mouse because that way you can disable them. So disable one hub at a time and if the mouse stops working, connect it to another USB port. If nothing helps, try restarting your computer several times and unplugging power.