# Cannot reconnect USB disk after exceeding power

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage

Due to a slightly defect cable Windows sometimes gives me a warning that the device is taking too much power (pop up in notification tray). It then gets disconected. Unfortunately, I cannot safely remove it, as it claims the disk is still in use. Usually, if Windows claims this, I do not care and remove the cable. In this particular case, however, the device remains shown. In the explorer I can even open some cached folders. If I reconnect the drive on another usb port, it is detected as new device but not displayed. I can remove that one safely now, but with no effect on the falsely shown one. It is present even after log-out log-in and still cannot be removed safely.
Is there a way of dealing with this apart from a restart ...and buying a new cable to avoid this to happen in the first place, of course.

[This discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/268680/usb-mass-storage-device-says-the-hub-power-has-been-exceeded) has an interesting answer, but I do not see an exclamation mark in my device manager.

**update**

Found it, but seems to require a restart, something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: After restart, it does not show up and I can connect "normally" (assuming the cable is positioned OK)

Comment: Do you recognise this device in **Device manager**? If yes, uninstall it from there and let it automatically install next time connected. Faulty devices/cables can cause your device or motherboard to fail!

Comment: Isn’t your *slightly defect cable* causing a short circuit for a moment? I’d prefer a hardware solution in that case.

Comment: @Melebius. It probably does. Actually, it is only the outer isolation, that is broken, so one may touch ground. That shouldn't be a problem though. There is only one laptop complaining about power (2 other laptops and one desktop are fine). In any case, my question would remain as: how does a proper removal take place after the above mentioned error.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV Logged in as administrator. Now I found the exclamation mark and the device was present in the disk section. Any removal action there resulted in "effect takes place after restart" though

Comment: Since this is a hardware issue, stopping and starting the power supply (what happens during a restart) is what doing the trick. Till then Windows assumes the device is active. Are you sure only the protective shield is damaged? That can cause interference, depending on where its placed or grounding or even short circuits.. . . . . . . . Proper removal of device will not happen as windows/hardware controller already tried to reduce/stop the current flow through the port.

Comment: Also, by default, devices are optimized for quick removal in Windows unless its changed by user.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV Difficult to be sure on what is actually damaged. My problem is: What is Windows actually doing here? If the Windows hardware controller stops power, why would it keep the device in the explorer as if nothing has happened....even after hard removal. What is the procedure for the user in such a case. After reboot everything is back to normal. But until then I have a Zombi-device.

Comment: In any case I agree that I should get a new cable soon.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV I think some LEDs are still working on the disk, so I guess it is, if at all, a power reduction.

Comment: If you know the cable is defective , just replace it, you can cause serious hardware damage if you continue to use a known defective cable.

Comment: Possibly the damaged cable created the zombie effect. If you open windows explorer for your USB hard disk and keep it till the hard disk is set to idle mode, you can browse a bit through the drive before the HDD starts to spin again. And the window will immediately close if you unplug it. So, here windows is somehow made yo belive the device is live. But seeing the same device ID on two ports may have caused not to show second.

Comment: I appreciate all the concern about my hardware. I know that this is not good and I will surely change that cable. To stick with the main issue, let me rephrase the question: Once I had a defective cable. Upon the message that the device uses to much power, I disconnected the divice, which still had some residual power and some LEDs glowing, as the option to safely remove did not work. This precidure left me with a zombi-device remaining in the explorer while physically removed: Is there a way to remove the zombi without a reboot.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV wrote the above comment before I read your last. OK I understand the possibility to browse. My problem is that a physical unplug does not remove the device. The same device ID on two ports is my bonus for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting is the easiest way to get the device cache flushed as well as recheck the presence of the device.

Since the faulty cable causing noise/Short circuit is involved, it really requires the power cycling.

Some questions related to device cache flushing:

- [how-to-clear-windows-file-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/78200/how-to-clear-windows-file-cache)
- [how-to-flush-the-disk-read-cache-under-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574168/how-to-flush-the-disk-read-cache-under-windows)

Comment: It probably comes down to a restart. It is amazing that there is no proper forced umount/eject possibility. All other solutions I found also need a restart, eventually. I should be happy that changing the desktop background does not require a restart in Windows. Apart from the fact that I seriously must change my cable, all this revealed inconveniences are ...well... inconvenient.